# Route protecting with custom claims

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an application that requires both an admin and user backends, I have managed to protect the routes depending on if the user is logged in however, I need users to not be able to access the admin backend.

I know I can do this with an if statement, however, nothing seems to be working!

I am using React redirects.

Currently, the admin has an "admin" token.

In theory, the if statement should just be:

```
if (!admin) {
  redirect to /userindex
}

else {
  return content 
}
```

I am wondering if anyone knows the best way of doing this?

**CODE**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../AdminIndex/AdminIndex.scss';



class AdminIndex extends Component {
  
    render() {
    // This checks if the user is logged in
      const { auth } = this.props
      if(!auth.uid) return <Redirect to = '/login' />
      
      return (
        <div className="AdminIndex">
            <h1> Admin Index</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    // console.log(state);
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps)
  )(AdminIndex)
```

Comment: And this does not work? Looks good to me. Have you console.logged the auth prop?

Comment: @Gh05d The code shown works however, it doesn't allow access based on their token but simply if the user are logged in or not. So currently, any user that is logged in can access the admin pages of the project.

Comment: You can use an admin token or - simpler - just add a property like `admin: true` into the users token. So you avoid code duplication.

Comment: @Gh05d Currently, I have an admin custom claim token on admin users. I'm just struggling in grabbing the token and putting that into the if statement I need. With the navigation I set the state depending on the token and then changed the nav depending on the state but that doesn't seem to be working here.

Answer (score 0):

javascript function to parse token

```js
    const _parseJwt = (token) => {
        return JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
      };
```

1. get user
2. get token
3. parse token
4. use plain object from parsed token

```js
const user = await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged
if(user){
     const token = await  user.getIdToken(true)
         const result = _parseJwt(token)
         alert(JSON.stringify(result , null, 2))
}
```